# Possible to do some kind of statistical analysis without N?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

So the thing is that I got some good data for my research project, but the problem is that the data I got only have percentages and standard errors, but no population (N). I would need to do some statistical analysis, so I was wondering if the data I got is useless for this purpose?

I am aware that this might be a lame question, but I have spent a lot of hours trying to find other datasets with a population with no luck, so I am kinda desperate.

Comment: Your use of the term "population" is confusing. Do you really mean that $N$ is the *sample* size?

Comment: Yes, N is the sample size.

Answer (score 0):

The estimated standard error SE = $\sqrt{\frac {\hat p (1-\hat p)}N}$. Given you have SE and $\hat p$, $N=\frac {\hat p (1-\hat p)}{\text{SE}^2}$. So if you need $N$, you can get it.

Comment: It seems your data really has problem. 0.977 means 0.977% or 97.7%? 0.98 means 0.98% or 98%?

Comment: Did you get the $N$s? So my answer is correct?